# Which side of door should I install a threshold draft excluder?

Tags: doors, sealing

I purchased this door bottom, [MD Building Products 3 ft. x 1-3/4 in. x 1-5/8 in. Vinyl Door-Bottom Moulding](http://www.homedepot.com/MD-Building-Products/h_d1/N-5yc1vZxj/R-100125047/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053), and the directions are straight forward except they don't indicate which side of the door you would screw this into.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking at the [installation guide (direct link to PDF)](http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/pdfImages/11/1172507a-6958-46d6-b7f2-87c635f97e54.pdf), it needs to be fixed to the door face that closes onto the stop beads (which are usually attached to the inside face of the door frame), or put another way, the opposite face from the hinges pins.

[image: Installation Guide]

Comment: Thank you, I guess I could have looked harder for the installation guide online